# Java Reddit Parser

Tags: java, android, json, buffer

I'm developing an android reddit app using [this wrapper](https://github.com/karan/jReddit). I'm able to login and everything but it's having some trouble parsing. Here's the code:

```
package com.example.reddit;

import im.goel.jreddit.submissions.Submission;
import im.goel.jreddit.submissions.Submissions;
import im.goel.jreddit.user.User;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private TextView username;
    private TextView password;
    private User reddit;
    private Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String usern = username.getText().toString();
                String passw = password.getText().toString();

                reddit = new User(usern, passw);
                try {
                    reddit.connect();

                    for (Submission submission : Submissions.getSubmissions("cfb",
                            Submissions.Popularity.HOT, Submissions.Page.FRONTPAGE, reddit)) {
                        submission.upVote();
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

The message the LogCat outputs upon running it and clicking the button is:

```
12-01 17:22:47.392: I/global(6955): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
12-01 17:22:48.452: I/System.out(6955): Response: {"kind": "Listing", "data": {"modhash": "42p97yhjc913d0d8fef0d29b8192d65e5a569cf9992512b5f1", "children": [{"kind": "t3", "data": {"domain": "self.CFB", "banned_by": null, "media_embed": {}, "subreddit": "CFB", "selftext_html": "&lt;!-- SC_OFF --&gt;&lt;div class=\"md\"&gt;&lt;p&gt;Post any pictures, videos, or gifs of highlights, players, coaches, stadiums, awesome plays, mascots, hot girls, etc, etc, as well as any requests of the above here.&lt;/p&gt;\n&lt;/div&gt;&lt;!-- SC_ON --&gt;", "selftext": "Post any pictures, videos, or gifs of highlights, players, coaches, stadiums, awesome plays, mascots, hot girls, etc, etc, as well as any requests of the above here.", "likes": null, "secure_media": null, "link_flair_text": null, "id": "1rs14o", "secure_media_embed": {}, "clicked": false, "stickied": true, "author": "CFB_Referee", "media": null, "score": 186, "approved_by": null, "over_18": false, "hidden": false, "thumbnail": "self", "subreddit_id": "t5_2qm9d", "edited": false, "link_flair_css_class": null, "a
12-01 17:22:48.482: W/System.err(6955): Unexpected token END OF FILE at position 1024.
12-01 17:22:48.492: W/System.err(6955):     at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:257)
12-01 17:22:48.492: W/System.err(6955):     at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:81)
12-01 17:22:48.492: W/System.err(6955):     at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:75)
12-01 17:22:48.492: W/System.err(6955):     at im.goel.jreddit.utils.Utils.get(Utils.java:116)
12-01 17:22:48.492: W/System.err(6955):     at im.goel.jreddit.submissions.Submissions.getSubmissions(Submissions.java:62)
12-01 17:22:48.492: W/System.err(6955):     at com.example.reddit.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:42)
12-01 17:22:48.492: W/System.err(6955):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
12-01 17:22:48.492: W/System.err(6955):     at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
12-01 17:22:48.492: W/System.err(6955):     at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6661)
12-01 17:22:48.502: W/System.err(6955):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
12-01 17:22:48.502: W/System.err(6955):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:924)
12-01 17:22:48.502: W/System.err(6955):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:924)
12-01 17:22:48.502: W/System.err(6955):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:924)
12-01 17:22:48.502: W/System.err(6955):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:924)
12-01 17:22:48.502: W/System.err(6955):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1695)
12-01 17:22:48.502: W/System.err(6955):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1116)
12-01 17:22:48.502: W/System.err(6955):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2068)
12-01 17:22:48.502: W/System.err(6955):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1679)
12-01 17:22:48.502: W/System.err(6955):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1708)
12-01 17:22:48.512: W/System.err(6955):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-01 17:22:48.512: W/System.err(6955):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-01 17:22:48.512: W/System.err(6955):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4595)
12-01 17:22:48.512: W/System.err(6955):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-01 17:22:48.512: W/System.err(6955):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-01 17:22:48.512: W/System.err(6955):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
12-01 17:22:48.512: W/System.err(6955):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
12-01 17:22:48.512: W/System.err(6955):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

So obviously it's pulling in the submission from the frontpage of /r/cfb but it's only able to read 1024 bytes. The error is `Unexpected token END OF FILE at position 1024`. Anyone know what that is or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The buffer was overflowing when retrieving the information. So instead of get and trying to store all the data reddit returns, we parse through it on the fly to only get the needed information and store it. More efficient and solves the buffer overflow error. Something like:

```
JSONArray array = (JSONArray) ((JSONObject) object.get("data"))
                .get("children");
JSONObject data;
for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
     data = (JSONObject) array.get(i);
}
```